# How to make datadriven menu and submenu with different user login in yii framework?

Tags: php, sql, yii

```
CREATE TABLE mainmenu (
  menuid int(10) NOT NULL,
  mainmenuname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  url varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (menuid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

this is mainmenu table

```
CREATE TABLE submenu (
  submenuid int(10) NOT NULL,
  menuid int(10) NOT NULL,
  submenuname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  url varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (submenuid),
  KEY menuid (menuid),
  CONSTRAINT submenu_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (menuid) REFERENCES mainmenu (menuid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

this is submenu table

```
CREATE TABLE user_rights (
  user_id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  submenuid int(3) NOT NULL,
  menuid int(3) NOT NULL,
  accessrole varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id,submenuid,menuid),
  KEY submenuid (submenuid),
  KEY menuid (menuid),
  CONSTRAINT user_rights_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id),
  CONSTRAINT user_rights_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (submenuid) REFERENCES submenu (submenuid),
  CONSTRAINT user_rights_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY (menuid) REFERENCES mainmenu (menuid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

this is user rights table

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  username varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  user_id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  accessrole varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

this is user table.

How to load menu and submenu from database associated with accessrole from user rights tbl?

Comment: thank you for editing. but if you could you help me in this question then its great.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so please add that code.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/295/database-driven-cmenu/

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/613/database-driven-cmenu/

Comment: i had taken reference of this both sites but its not working for my need

Comment: What do you mean not working? Are any items being displayed? Are the wrong items being displayed? Is there a specific error?

Comment: i am a newbie for yii. and for mvc concepts . so if u could tell me a code according to my tables then its would be great for me. thank you topher

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a separate menu and submenu table, create a single table with column int 'parentID'.

Create an iterative function to process / display each submenu.

```
<code>
private function processBranch($branch) {
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition('parentID = ' . $branch);
$criteria->addCondition('accessrole = ' . $this->access);

$menuitems = Menu::model()->findAll($criteria);
if(!empty($menuitems)) {
    foreach($menuitems as $item) {
        // EcHo menu content here

        $this->processBranch($item->id);
    }
}
}
```

Display root menu with processBranch(0)

Comment: this is hierachical menu list. this is not my requirement. if u could help me in my question then its very usefull to me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your data modeling is that every "mainmenu" must have at least one "submenu"  . Is it the real need ?

Comment: if you can give a code according to my tables then it would b great. thnk uuu